# Unix scripting - for do command with &

Tags: shell-script

I am trying to use a for do command that I can run as a one liner in Solaris/Linux, and would like the do command to run asynchronously.  I have tried the following:

```
for i in `ls AMQ*.FMT`; do ./mqtrcfrmt.solaris $i $i.2 &; done
```

but I get an error like the following:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Is there a way to get the do part of this for/do command to recognize the ampersand (&) and run this command asynchronously?

Comment: In my post, there should have been a ` before and after the ls AMQ*.FMT.

Answer (score 1):

Do not put a semi-colon after the `&`. Otherwise this would mean that there is an empty command after it.